# How to include all resources into one html file?

Tags: c#, html

is there any c# library or any free tool which can convert a html file with many referenced resources into a one "all-in-one" html file?

The main task is to have only one file, it means I need to include

1. Javascript external files - this will probably mean replace all 'script' tags
   with 'src' attribute by 'script' tags with content read from referenced file.
2. Images - replace src="picture.png" with data uri - something like  src="data:image/png;base64,encodedContent..."
3. CSS files
4. may be i forgot something :)

This HTML file must be readable in all browsers, that's why I cannot use MHT file format (unreadable on Safari, iPad...)

Comment: And why not use the build action "Content" to copy out the files on publish? What's the point of making them as resources?

Comment: @Ingenu I cannot see that he is refering to a build-context. He simply wants to get an HTML document from an arbitrary URL and make this a self-contained document.

Comment: Exactly. I'm not the author of the original HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to go read/write the html document. HTML Agility supports XPath so you can get a list of nodes you want to modify.

Using this, changing the attribute value of image tags should be easy. You can also get a list of external js references, read them and then update the script tag accordingly.

Comment: I know about "HTML Agility Pack" and that will be probably the way I will use if I won't find any other solution. The problem will be not to forget to include something and I will have to write it all from scratch. That's why I am looking for a finished "solution".